# Load NSViewController from Nib

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nsviewcontroller

Can I load an NSViewController with its view and all the subvews from a Nib file as I usually do in UIKit with initWithNibName:bundle:? In AppKit I can load an NSWindowController with that message, but if I try to load an NSViewController, although the view is not nil, it won't show. Is there a known way to do this?

EDIT: It works if I add the view programmatically with addSubview:, it doesn't if I use an outlet to a custom view in the main nib and then replace.

Comment: It *should* work. How are you showing the view?

Comment: Custom view in the main window, outlet in the AppDelegate

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that when you are trying to load a view this way, it gets just 'lazy-loaded'.
You should try to access something from that view after that to get the view fully loaded and displayed.